# Bash remove line with zero value

Tags: bash, file, cut

I have a file which is 1500 lines long containing cpu values, but somehow there is 0 very second line. Is it possible to remove every second line containing only 0 in a bash command ?

```
8
0
9
0
10
0
10
0
8
0
9
0
```

Comment: Do you want to remove every line with zero, or remove every second line, or remove every second line that is zero?

Comment: What do you mean by "cpu values"? What is this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove all zeros**

Use `grep -v`:

```
-v, --invert-match
             Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns.
```

Command:

```
grep -v -e "^0$" file
```

The problem with this is that it will remove lines **all** '0' lines.

**Remove even lines**

```
awk 'NR % 2 != 0' file
```

In this case, you have to be sure that all even lines are the ones you want to remove.

**Remove even lines that are '0'**

```
awk 'NR % 2 != 0 || ! /0/' file
```

Comment: Will -v 0 work ? I dont want it to remove lines where value is 10 for example. Only where it is 0.

Comment: grep -v -e "^0$" will work since it will remove the lines where it is only 0. Right ?

Comment: Exactly. ^ means line-start and $ means line-end.

Comment: why `cat file | grep -v -e "^0$"` and not just `grep -v -e "^0$" file` ?

Comment: grep -v -e '^0$' isn't correct. My file is 1450 lines and removing half of them should be 725. With  grep -v -e '^0$' its returning 719 lines.

Comment: @iknowpython Are you sure that *exactly* half the lines are 0's?

Comment: I believe somewhere not every second line there was not 0, and it removed it also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete every second line, but only if it contains a `0`, then this one liner will help:

`awk '($0 == 0) && (NR % 2 == 0) { next } { print }' cpu_values.txt`

It means, if the input line equals 0, and it is an even line, then skip it. Otherwise, print the line.